# Finding details of flash stream using Firebug, to record

Tags: firefox, streaming, video-streaming, firebug

I can find some of the details of a Flash stream using Firebug, but I want to know exactly which details I need in order to capture the stream.

It gets details such as a url ending in: jwplayer-3.5.0.0, or the domain trtcanlitv-lh.akamaihd.net. But I can't find how to use either of these to capture the channel to record it.

An example of the channel I want to record is any of the [TRT](http://www.trt.net.tr/anasayfa/canli.aspx?y=tv&k=trt1) channels.

Most guides I have found are about RTMP capture, whilst this is not of that protocol.

So what details from Firebug would I need, and how would I capture it? I am using Linux, but I can use Windows if that is the easiest way. Terminal commands preferably, so that I can set specific times for recording.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: [YouTube-DL](http://youtube-dl.org/) to download flash-based video.  Don't misunderstand the name of the program, it works on many more sites than just YouTube.  You can get it from that link or just install Python and in a command shell enter `pip install youtube-dl` and periodically `pip install --upgrade youtube-dl` to keep it up-to-date.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the streaming aspect, but it might still work.

Comment: i can see how to download a video, but not from a continous stream like the one i have. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you open this and observe the Network activity with Firefox web developer "Network" view, then you'll see lots of downloads of e.g. about 0.5 MB. Also some tiny files. The large files are of type video/f4f.

This tells me, that this is a progressive download type of delivery. Possibly with switching to different bandwidth adaptive chunk sizes.

Unless this uses DRM it should be fairly easy to isolate the request that yields the initial playlist and issue that from / feed that to, some suitable player/converter software of choice. (Sorry, not familiar with any.)